# Actionscript object number of properties

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, object, flash-cs5

How can I get the number of properties in a generic Actionscript Object? (Like Array length)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will have to loop over all element to count them:

```
function objectLength(myObject:Object):int {
 var cnt:int=0;

 for (var s:String in myObject) cnt++;

 return cnt;
}

var o:Object={foo:"hello", bar:"world"};
trace(objectLength(o)); // output 2
```

Comment: Seems to call out for a better API, such as javascript's Object.keys()

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter code here:

```
var o:Object={foo:"hello",bar:"world",cnt:2};
trace(o.cnt);  // output  2;
```

Just remember to update the very last argument in the object list if ever anything is added to it.  That's the main downside to this approach, I think.  And now, of course, the `.cnt` does not actually return the true list length, but rather it is the list length - 1.

Comment: This could get tricky. `cnt` could become inaccurate in cases where a property overwrites an already-existing property, or when a property gets deleted without existing. Thus, checks would be needed every time the object is modified.